# Calculate Date/Time Difference in Java considering AM/PM

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, date-difference

I want to calculate the difference between two date/time in java using Date and Calendar classes. The format that I have is "2012-01-24 12:30:00 PM".

I have implemented my own method and also google it to work with others, but haven't getting the right hint to handle AM and PM values.

The date/time difference got troubled whenever the time have 12(AM/PM) in it. For example if I have date/time "2012-01-24 12:30:00 PM" and "2012-01-24 02:30:00 PM" it shows the difference is 10 hours.

Considering the code on [this link](http://technojeeves.com/joomla/index.php/free/71-difference-between-two-dates-in-java) how can it be modified to handle AM and PM.

To convert String date into Date I use following code:

```
    String sessionTimeStart = "2012-01-24 12:30:00 PM";
    String sessionTimerEndOrCurrent = "2012-01-24 02:30:00 PM";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"); 

    Date d1 = null;
    Date d0 = null; 
    try {
        d1 = format.parse(sessionTimeStart);
        d0 = format.parse(sessionTimerEndOrCurrent);
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: How do you convert the string to a `Date` object? And how do you calculate the difference? If you use the code you linked, how do you call it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is your date format: instead of `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a` use `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a`.

`HH` will be the hour in day (0-23) whereas `hh` will be the hour in AM/PM (1-12). Thus with your date format 02:30:00 will be parsed as just that instead of being converted to the PM version (which in hour of day would be 14:30:00).

Comment: I think you are right @Thomas . I will try changing it to 'hh' and test all my cases.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why it shows 10 hours as the difference is that you've got an error in the pattern when parsing the input.

Here's an example using `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a");

Date date1 = df.parse("2012-01-24 12:30:00 PM");
Date date2 = df.parse("2012-01-24 02:30:00 PM");

long differenceInHours = Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60);
```

Will return `10`.

When we just slightly change the date format pattern, using `hh` for hour in am/pm (1-12) instead of `HH` for hour in day (0-23):

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
```

It returns (the expected) `2`.

See the [documentation for `SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to get your patterns right.

Answer (score 4):

So, you have these dates as strings? Parse them with a `SimpleDateFormat` with the appropriate format string, and compute the difference in hours:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");

Date d1 = df.parse("2012-01-24 12:30:00 PM");
Date d2 = df.parse("2012-01-24 02:30:00 PM");

int hoursDifference = (int)((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 3600000L);
System.out.println("Difference in hours: " + hoursDifference);
```

Your error is that you are using **HH** (24-hour hours) instead of **hh** (12-hour hours) in your format string.

Comment: Thanks @Jesper , I will try your solution as well. But the HH and hh seems to be the case that i am missing here

Answer (score 2):

Don't build it yourself, use an established library. [Jodatime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is used widely.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @his. But as I mentioned I have to use Date and Calendar classes.

Answer (score 1):

onsider using [Apache Commons DateUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DurationFormatUtils.html) DurationFormatUtils formatPeriod method will do the magic.

Good luck!

EDIT
Assuming that you have Date a and Date b initialized at this point,

```
String format="HH:mm:ss.SSS";   // whatever you wish
boolean padWithZeros=true; // whatever you wish
TimeZone timezone=null; // whatever you wish
long timeA = a.getTime();
long timeB = b.getTime();

String period = DurationFormatUtils.formatPeriod(timeB, timeA, format, padWithZeros, timezone);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @aviad. But as I mentioned I have to use Date and Calendar classes.

Answer (score -1):

Calendar has a methode add() that can be used for substracting too. Take a look at it. You should be using Calendar instead of Date anyway because most of the Date operations are deprecated.

Comment: The question was about calculating the difference not about comparison.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the API. Thought compareTo() would return the the difference in Milliseconds.